# ceiling fan and recessed lights on same circuit

Tags: wiring

Question. Can I wire switches that allow me to operate a ceiling fan without power going to the other lights?

Situation.  Builder put  both the ceiling fan and recessed lights on the same wire run in the cathedral ceiling. The wire is 12-2 romex and the circuit consists of 6 recessed lights and a ceiling fan which is located at the end of the circuit. The wire for this circuit (and all the other ceiling light circuits) is dropped down from the ceiling to run in a chase to be later hooked to power and switches. The lights and fan are not connected yet but I can not add additional wiring in the ceiling. [image][image]

Comment: If they are all on the same circuit, You could get a Smart FAN and smart switch combo to control the fan and lights via wifi or bluetooth over the same HOT.

Answer (score 1):

If there is one and only one run of 12/2 NM cable to the lights and fan, then you're out of luck using standard, simple wiring methods. I'd re-check and make sure there's not some 12/3 up there or an additional cable.

There are many types of smart devices out there that could help. There are smart light bulbs that can be turned on and off without the power being switched and ceiling fans can be purchased with remotes. You will have to do some research on what will work best for you.